# Cake php query for limit that returns starting record no and total no records

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, limit

I am new to the CakePHP framework, and am here with very simple question:

```
SELECT * from quiz_questions LIMIT 1,2
```

How can I write the above in CakePHP3?

What I tried:

```
$this->QuizQuestions->find()->limit(1,2);
```

And:

```
$this->QuizQuestions->find()->limit([1,2]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this query.

```
$query = $this->QuizQuestions->find()
->limit(50)
->page(2);
```

Comment: What you are showing there will not generate what the OP asked for, it will create SQL that is equivalent to `LIMIT 50, 50`, in fact it's not possible to generate an offset of `1` and a limit of `2` by using `limit()` and `page()`, as that way the offset will always be a multiple of the limit. There is an `offset()` method to set the exact offset value for the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

```
 $this->QuizQuestions->find('all', array('limit'=>1, 'offset'=>2));
```